# php session_start() with xampp and gulp

Tags: php, cross-domain, session-cookies

I have an issue using php sessions.

My development environment:

Back-end : Xampp with PHP and MySql

Front-end : Gulp.

Calling http://localhost:3000 for the client.

Calling http://localhost/request.php for backend requests

Request.php:

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 include_once 'Utilities/Logger.php';
 include_once 'Utilities/Error.php';
 include_once 'Database.php';
 include_once 'RequestHandler.php';
 include_once 'ServerConfiguration.php';
//setting the sessionId to che

$sessionId = session_id();

....
?>
```

I store the generated sessionid on the client and send it everytime to the server to check if they match.
Everytime i call request.php an new session is created.
I see cookies are stored in C:\xampp\tmp

Does it have to do with the fact I'm using http://localhost:3000 and http://localhost?

Somebody who can help me?

Thanks,

**Update:**

My connection manager (responsible for connecting a user):

```
 $_SESSION['username'] = $user->UserName;
 $_SESSION['UserID'] = $user->UserID;
 $_SESSION['Language'] = $userPreferences->Language;
 $userSessionData = new UserSessionData();
 $userSessionData->SessionId = $sessionId;
```

Comment: You are not saving anything YET to `$_SESSION` Global.

Comment: I do! So my request.php is called, this calls depending on the type of request in this case the connection manager. Once a user is connected we send that back to the client, everytime the client makes a server call this sessionid is send to the server for verification.